# long form dataset to long(er) form dataset using pivot_longer

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying my `input` dataset to look like the `output`: I have tried: `pivot_longer(input, hyp, math)` from `library(tidyverse)` without success.

Is there a way to achieve my desired output?

```
input <- read.csv("https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/nlsy_math_hyp_long.csv")

#==== A few rows of desired output:

       id var grade d_math d_hyp  grp
1     201  38     3      1     0 math
2     201  55     5      1     0 math
3     303  26     2      1     0 math
4     303  33     5      1     0 math
5    2702  56     2      1     0 math
```

Comment: can you please explain the `d_math` and `d_hyp` based on the input.  In input, there are columns 'male', 'female', 'spring', 'anti' etc

Comment: @akrun, `d_hyp` and `d_math` are simply two binary variables created after elongating the dataset. When `grp` is `math` in the elongated dataset, `d_math` is `1` else is `0`. Similarly, when `grp` is `hyp` in the elongated dataset, `d_hyp` is `1` else is `0`.

Comment: Some info is missing.  In the 'grp' column, how many variables from input are reshaped

Comment: @akrun, I have a long solution: `math <- data.frame(id     = input$id, 
                   var    = input$math, 
                   grade  = input$grade,
                   d_math = 1, 
                   d_hyp  = 0, 
                   grp    = 'math');

hyp <- data.frame(id     = input$id,
                  var    = input$hyp,
                  grade  = input$grade,
                  d_math = 0,
                  d_hyp  = 1,
                  grp    = 'hyp');

output <- rbind(math, hyp)`  just want to find a shorter solution possibly.

Comment: I guess you need to `select` the columns first `input %>% select(id, grade, math, hyp) %>% pivot_longer(cols = math:hyp, names_to = 'grp', values_to = 'var') %>% mutate(d_math = +(grp == 'math'), d_hyp = +(grp == 'hyp'))%>% arrange(desc(grp), id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `select` the columns of interest and do the pivoting

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
input %>%
    select(id, grade, math, hyp) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = math:hyp, names_to = 'grp', values_to = 'var') %>% 
    mutate(d_math = +(grp == 'math'), 
           d_hyp = +(!d_math))%>% 
    arrange(desc(grp), id)
```